# Does initiation of a link force another changling to assume liquid form?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Whenever you see changlings initiate a link, one of them takes the other in the hands, and then assumes liquid state. The receiving changling then starts to assume liquid form as well. It isn't clear to me whether this is always voluntary or not.

Does contact with a liquid form changling cause another changling to also revert to liquid form? Or does the receiving changling have to comply with the link?

I'm wondering if Odo could have wandered around touching people with his arm in liquid state to identify other changlings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the episode [Homefront](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Homefront_%28episode%29) Odo suspects Admiral Leyton to be replaced by a changeling. He then grabs Leyton's arm and assumes liquid form. After a few seconds Leyton's arm also becomes liqiud.

So it seems that Odo forced the other changeling into assuming liquid form.

[Picture from Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/File%3aEarthbound_Changeling.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

As with a lot of things in DS9, the writers probably didn't think that far into it or purposely left it ambiguous (i.e. some changelings can force others, but Odo can't because he's not as well trained in his changeling abilities).

I do remember a scene ([*"The Adversary"*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Adversary_%28episode%29) as Jared correctly identified) where one changling shoves his hand into Odo's chest or gut and puts him in a lot of agony. So it's at least possible for a highly skilled changeling to forcibly meld with a younger or less skillful changling:
[image: The Krajensky Changeling attacks Odo.]

I doubt there's an in-canon explanation for this though. Just like there isn't one for:

- how changelings see or hear;
- why all the changelings seem to assume similar humanoid shapes even though they repeatedly insist that changelings don't have a natural solid form;
- why the number of changelings can't be counted even though outside of the link they seem to have distinct and consistent identities which "each" changeling always appears as;
- why all the changelings have similar noses/mouths/hair to Odo, even though Odo had randomly chosen his hairstyle to resemble Dr. Mora's and his nose was supposedly due to his ineptness at emulating humanoid noses;
- why Loz was the only changeling capable of assuming the form of chemical processes (fire) and scattered matter (fog);

Comment: On point 2, the female changeling says to Odo the first time they meet, something like, they chose a humanoid form because it makes interacting with the solids easier - because we're all used to humanoids.

Comment: @Izkata: I understand that, but why is it that there's a characteristically "changeling" humanoid form that even changelines which achieved sapience tens of thousands of lightyears apart naturally adopt? If changelings really don't have an intrinsic solid shape, then you'd expect the humanoid form taken by changelings to have much more variation rather than being so uniform.

Comment: I think the scene you are referring to was in episode "The Adversary" and theres a great picture on the wiki page from memory alpha (can't link it for some reason =/)

Comment: @Lèsemajesté I'd go with Odo's comment early in the series:  That particular humanoid form, having so few facial features/etc, is simple and easy.  They may be more skilled and able to produce more variation, but why should they?  The changelings don't like solids.

Comment: The first time that we see a changeling other than Odo take human form, is in the season three premiere, The Search. Here, I believe the "female changeling" takes a human form that is similar to Odo's so that it shows him they're the same. There's nothing to suggest that the other members of the Great Link assume an Odo-like shape before his return to them.

Comment: @TZHX: So you're saying that Odo's return caused a species-wide shift in their humanoid form? What would be the point? Simply to impress Odo? Or would the entire link alter their humanoid appearance every time one of the hundred returned? It seems really far-fetched considering the founders regularly interacted with Vorta, Jem'Hadar and other humanoids of the Dominion and thus must have already had a traditional appearance (which Vorta and Jem'Hadar are genetically programmed to recognize).